# How to show $f(0)\leq \lim_{t\to a} f(t) +Ca$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Fix $a>0.$ Let $f:[0,a)\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable funtion such that $|f'(x)|\leq C$  for all $x\in [0, a)$ and $C>0$ some fix constant.

> My Question: Can we say $f(0)\leq \lim_{t\to a} f(t) +Ca$?

Comment: What did you try to do so far?

Comment: I am thinking to apply Taylor expansion, but in that there are so many terms!!

Comment: Try the Mean-Value theorem.

Comment: You cant really apply taylor expansion except for the $n=1$ case (which is the mean value theorem), since $f'$ might not be differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the mean value theorem,
$$f(t)-f(0)=t'f(s)$$
for some $s\in(0,t)\subset(0,a)$. Thus
$$
f(0)=f(t)-tf'(s)\le f(t)+Ct\le f(t)+Ca
$$
which also is valid under the limes.